# Use Pattern-Templates inside Regex?

Tags: regex, templates

I'm wondering if it's possible to use something like custom Pattern Templates inside Regular Expressions. A simple example:

```
# this regex
^1xyz2xyz3xyz4$
# matches this string
"1xyz2xyz3xyz4"
```

As one can see, I have to use "xyz" three times, so my question is: can I define a template once for "xyz" and then use the template name in the rest of the regex?

Comment: You can kind of do that with backreferences if your regex engine supports them.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl and PCRE you can use `(?(DEFINE)...)` blocks to declare named groups and then call them as named regexes:

```
my $re = qr{
    (?(DEFINE) (?<tmp> xyz )  )
    ^ 1 (?&tmp) 2 (?&tmp) 3 (?&tmp) 4  $
}x;

print "1xyz2xyz3xyz4" =~ $re;
```